# Sprite Kit Scene won't present

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am currently working on a game that consists of three scenes, the GameScene, ArcheryScene, and GameOverScene. When I start the game the GameScene presents just fine, then I tap on the screen to start the game and the ArcheryScene presents just fine. The GameOverScene gets triggered when a contact is made in the game, and it works as well. However, once the GameOverScene is presented I would like to be able to tap on the screen to go back to the ArcheryScene and restart the game. However when I tap on the screen, nothing happens, at all. Any advice or suggestions would be great appreciated, thank you.

GameScene Code that presents the ArcheryScene when tapped: (works)

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

    let welcomeNode = childNodeWithName("welcomeNode")

        if (welcomeNode != nil) {
            let fadeAway = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1.0)

            welcomeNode?.runAction(fadeAway, completion: {
                let doors = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 1.0)
                let archeryScene = ArcheryScene(fileNamed: "ArcheryScene")
                archeryScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                self.view?.presentScene(archeryScene, transition: doors)
            })
        }

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

ArcheryScene code that presents the GameOverScene when a contact is made: (works)

```
let fadeOut = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0)])
            let welcomeReturn = SKAction.runBlock({
                let Transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 1.0)
                let gameOverScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameOverScene")
                gameOverScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                self.scene!.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: Transition)
            })
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, welcomeReturn])
            self.runAction(sequence)
```

GameOverSceneCode that presents the ArcheryScene when tapped: (doesn't work)

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameOverScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

    }

   override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        let gameOverNode = childNodeWithName("gameOverNode")

        if (gameOverNode != nil) {

            let fadeAway2 = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1.0)

            gameOverNode?.runAction(fadeAway2, completion: {
                let doors2 = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 1.0)
                let archeryScene = ArcheryScene(fileNamed: "ArcheryScene")
                archeryScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                self.view?.presentScene(archeryScene, transition: doors2)
            })
        }

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the touch event run? Set a breakpoint to find out.

Comment: I just tried this, the touch isn't even running

Comment: then set self.userInteractionEnabled = YES

Comment: in your archery code i notice self.scene!.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: Transition)
everywhere else you are using self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: Transition)

Answer (score 0):

gameOverNode doesnt exist.  Youre saying `let gameOverNode = childNodeWithName("gameOverNode")`..  gameOverNode is nil!  It's nothing, and so that block of code in the conditional statement isnt doing anything.

you need to add a node named "gameOverNode" in order to reference it.   `childNodeWithName` references a node that already exists in your scene.. its not creating a new one.

Comment: But gameOverNode does exist. Just like welcomeNode exists in the GameScene file. And to prove that this isn't the problem I changed the if statement statement to:    'if ( gameOverNode == nil )'   and this still didn't make the code run. So then I took the if statement completely out and it still didn't work, any other suggestions?

Comment: put a println in gameOverNode?.runAction  
does anything show up in the log?

Comment: I just tried what you said, nothing showed up in the log. Also I tried placing the println outside of the gameOverNode?.runAction, directly below the touchesBegan() function. Nothing showed up in the log when I tapped on the screen.. I am clueless as to why this isn't working. I can't see anything that I've done wrong.

Comment: nothing came up in the log because gameOverNode is nil.  when you put that question mark after something.. it means "if i dont exist, dont do anything"  try doing gameOverNode!.runAction and see what happens.  put a println right after touchesBegan and see if you get anything.

Comment: If you read my previous comment you'll see that I already tried placing the println right after touchesBegan, nothing appeared in the log. And I can assure you that gameOverNode does exist I created it myself, the gameOverNode is not the problem.